# Magento Cart and Checkout redirects to https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/bridge

Tags: checkout, paypal, third-party-module

I have this really weird problem where if I go to my cart or to the checkout page, it redirects me to https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/bridge.

There's no Paypal module enabled in my Magento site, but it just redirects to paypal.com/webapps/hermes/bridge which is really really weird. This just happened all of a sudden.

I have tried enabled then disabling the Paypal module, but it still redirects on the hermes bridge page. I hope somebody here encountered the same problem as I did.

(I cannot comment yet so i have to suggest edit. I have the exact same problem. Can you list out what all extensions are you using? If there are some common ones maybe we could isolate the culprit)

Comment: you have probably some custom extension installed?

Comment: Yep, but not Paypal related. Anyway, the problem occurs randomly. Sometimes it appears, sometimes it's not redirecting. I think I'll just observe it and disabled modules one by one. I'm just hoping someone here already encountered the same issue, but I guess nobody encountered it here. :(

Comment: @Anmol Goel - I have IWD OPC, Wfs_DisableCompare, AddThis_PluginsGeneral, AddThis_SharingTool, and AddThis_SmartLayers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it.

The plugin IWD - One Page Checkout enables Paypal lightbox.

1) Go to System -> Settings -> IWD Extensions -> One Page Checkout

2) Disable "Enable Paypal Express Lightbox"